# Search pattern and remove pattern without affecting the rest of the line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I need to remove a 3 character substring from a document, which could be located anywhere in the document, eg.

```
text
text
text
bla bla bla -ri bla bla bla
text
text
text
```

I would like to search for -ri and remove it to obtain

```
text
text
text
bla bla bla bla bla bla
text
text
text
```

If this were a fixed line and character number I'm pretty sure I could excise it with sed or cut, but I am not sure how to do it if the line and character position are variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to know the line number, you can have `sed` unconditionally (try to) modify each and every line:

```
$ sed -e 's/-ri //' < input > output
```

It gets more awkward if you have matches on multiple lines, and want to handle only some of them.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` can be used for tasks like this:

```
sed 's/-ri //g' path/to/file
```

will find every occurance of `-ri` and replace it with nothing using the `s` substitute operate in sed